# Is the size of a Spark partition after decompression or before decompression if the input data is compressed (and splittable)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I understood that the size of a spark partition during dataframe loading stage is determined by the following values:

- Total input data size and the number of files
- The file format property (PARQUET vs. CSV, splittable, ...)
- spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes
- spark.default.parallelism
- spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes

Let's say a partition size is determined to be 128MB and if input files are compressed, splittable, and bigger than 128MB, then does a partition contain compressed data up to 128MB, or is it after decompression? I presumed it is the former but I want to double-check.